# CUDA5 Examples: Has anyone translated some cutil definitions to CUDA5?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

Has anyone started to work with the CUDA5 SDK?
I have an old project that uses some cutil functions, but they've been abandoned in the new one.

The solution was that most functions can be translated from cutil*/cut* to a similar named sdk* equivalent from the helper*.h headers...

As an example:
cutStartTimer becomes sdkCreateTimer
Just that simple...

Comment: "Has anyone started to work with the CUDA5 SDK?" - probably. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @l4mpi: The question is *extremely* clear. He/She has code using the unsupported cutil library that ships in older version of the SDK. Now it apparently doesn't ship with CUDA 5 and the question is what to do about it.

Comment: @talonmies Well, given the fact that cuda5 isn't even released yet and cutil has been removed in the examples, the question is rather why he doesn't just use the new headers that are intended to replace cutil...

Answer (score 16):

> Has anyone started to work with the CUDA5 SDK?

Probably.

> Has anyone translated some cutil definitions to CUDA5?

Maybe. But why not just use the new header files intended to replace it? Quoted from the [Beta release notes](http://code.google.com/p/cuda-5/source/browse/CUDA_SDK_Release_Notes.wiki?repo=wiki&r=7d5198768390e32b964a038fdaeaf86704880b21):

> Prior to CUDA 5.0, CUDA Sample projects referenced a utility library
>   with header and source files called cutil.  This has been removed with
>   the CUDA Samples in CUDA 5.0, and replaced with header files found
>   in CUDA Samples\v5.0\C\common\inc
>
> ```
> helper_cuda.h, helper_cuda_gl.h, helper_cuda_drvapi.h, helper_functions.h,
> helper_image.h, helper_math.h, helper_string.h, and helper_timer.h
> ```
>
> These files provide utility functions for CUDA device initialization,
>   CUDA error checking, string parsing, image file loading and saving, and
>   timing functions.  The CUDA Samples projects no longer have references
>   and dependencies to cutil, and will now use these helper functions
>   going forward.

Comment: +1. CUTIL, as has been stated many times (including in its readme in past versions), was never intended for use outside of SDK examples.

Comment: @harrism So this means helper_* headers are also in the samples directory and not intented to be used outside of SDK samples?

Comment: More information may be found at the release notes of CUDA 5.0 http://code.google.com/p/cuda-5/source/browse/CUDA_SDK_Release_Notes.wiki?repo=wiki&r=7d5198768390e32b964a038fdaeaf86704880b21

Comment: CUDA_SAFE_CALL(..) is replaced by checkCudaErrors(..) which is available in helper_cuda.h file.