# Workaround cutil.h

Tags: cuda, installation

I'm trying to use a software package called GPU-HMMER that was configured using CUDA 2.2.
However, it throws the following error:

```
cuda_kernel.cu:1:19: fatal error: cutil.h: No such file or directory
```

I realize that CUDA 5.0 doesn't have this file and I'm unsure about how I can properly install this software using CUDA 5.0

A similar problem was posted at the following link:

[CUDA5 Examples: Has anyone translated some cutil definitions to CUDA5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474191/cuda5-examples-has-anyone-translated-some-cutil-definitions-to-cuda5)

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: you can load [an earlier cuda sdk](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive) (samples) (such as 4.1) build it under CUDA 5, and then you should have everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem when I was trying to compile the CUDA samples.  I just did a quick google for cutil.h and found an old version being hosted on assembla.

[Cutil.h on Assembla.](https://www.assembla.com/code/cuda/subversion/nodes/NVIDIA%20GPU%20Computing%20SDK/C/common/inc/cutil.h?rev=5)

Comment: Okay.  I found that same link.  Were you able to successfully install anything with it?

Comment: Hmm.  This seems to be working for the moment.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I just find out that the Assembla link is broken.  Another copy of cutil.h can be found at the following link

www2.icmc.usp.br/~castelo/CUDA/.../inc/cutil.h